# Spark version 2.0 Streaming : how to dynamically infer the schema of a JSON String rdd and convert it to a DF

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

With versions prior to 2.0, I could use an SQLContext to do the same like this:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
                  ssc, kafkaParams, Set("myTopicName"))

stream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
     val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2)) //converts json to DF
     //do your operations on this DF. You won't even require a model class.
        })
```

but with latest versions, SQLContext seems to be deprecated. So, how do I create a DF out of a JSON String RDD without specifying the schema? I could find examples for the conversion using a schema with a `case class` or a `StructType` object, but the only option I could see to dynamically create a DF is using implicit reflection using `SparkSession` which doesn't seem to work well either. Is the support for schemaless JSON String to DataFrame taken out by the Spark team?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with latest versions, SQLContext seems to be deprecated.

Everything you can do with `SQLContext` can done be done with  `SparkSession` so just use it as drop in replacement.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

stream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
     val dataFrame = spark.read.json(rdd.map(_._2).toDS) 
  })
```